# Permission Denied on UserAdd command shell script started by PHP exec

Tags: php, exec, centos7

I've a PHP exec command which starts a bash script in Linux Centos 7.2

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
mkdir /var/www/html/folder1/$1

useradd -g usergroup -d /var/www/html/folder1/$1 $1
```

The sudoers is configured this way. 'apache' is the Apache User and Group in my installation:

```
apache    ALL=(ALL) ALL
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd
```

The mkdir command works as expected.
But the useradd command retrieves a 'permission denied' error even if I explicitly decleared in sudoers that the group/user apache has permission to execute useradd.

So How to solve this ? How to create a user which belongs to an already defined usergroup without getting 'permission denied' ?

Comment: As seen in this [sudoers configuration post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132821), shouldn't the group name be prefixed with a `%`?

Comment: Where is this code related to PHP?

Comment: Apache is an user not a group. Should be a group?

Comment: is apache the user executing the php script? not www-data?

Comment: I cannot find any www-data . Only an apache user in the users list of my linux distro so i supposed that my apache version uses a different name for the user and it worked for mkdir. I got before on mkdir the same permission issue before editing sudoers. Now mkdir works but useradd never worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting full permissions to the useradd file this way:

```
chmod 7777 /usr/sbin/useradd
```

I don't know if this is safe enough anyway it worked.
I continue after this getting a secondary error like:

nscd: Only root is allowed to use this option

It is related to the user cache cleaning failed by the useradd module. 
But at least the user at this stage is correctly added.
No idea at the moment if the failed cache flush could cause some other problems in the future.

EDIT: I had also to 1) do "chown root:root myscript.php" for my php script. 2) to put the bash script in /usr/sbin  3) make the bash script executable with chmod +x 4) execute it in php with : "sudo bashscript.sh"  4) and/or to add the /usr/sbin directory in sudoers security section